# django multiple model in dictionary json

Tags: ajax, django, json

I want to pass to create a json output with a dictionary with multiple models, like this:

```
results = {}
results["game_info_db"] = db.gameInfo.objects.get(name='name')
results["dlc_list_db"] = db.gameAddon.objects.filter(game__name='name')
```

What i tried is serialize (serializers.serialize) all dicts entrys and after this i dumps (simplejson.dumps) all the dict... but it doesn't seems to be correct ...

any sugestion ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what is not working as expected?

Comment: Can you also show the serialized code on the models and what the simplejson.dumps code looks like before pushing it back to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in the values of the models and convert it to a list:

```
results = {}
results["game_info_db"] = list(db.gameInfo.objects.get(name='name').values())
results["dlc_list_db"] = list(db.gameAddon.objects.filter(game__name='name').values())

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

The data will appear as objects on the javascript side.  Assuming you have a `name` column, you can access the attributes like the following:

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/", function(data) {
    var dlcs = data.dlc_list_db;
    for (i = 0; i < dlcs.length; i++) {
        var dlc = dlcs[i];
        alert(dlc.name);
    }
});
```